# Why is my question still closed even after I revised it?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I asked [Insert a client file into a column on a server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474862/insert-a-client-file-to-a-column-on-server-database). Admittedly, the post was originally not very good. After four minutes, I saw a message saying that I needed to revise my post, so I did.

About a minute later, the question was closed.

What should I do? Can the question somehow be reopened? Should I repost the good version?

Comment: It's reopened. -

Comment: I love the irony of this question being closed after the originally closed question was re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a reasonable question and I voted to reopen. I hope 4 others (and/or a moderator) will do the same.

**Update:** The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You did not do any editing; [all you added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7474862/revisions) was:

> Is that even possible in SQL?

Comment: I still don't see why it's not a valid question? I see much worse every day.

Comment: Well... yeah but isn't it do all the difference?